# Passing drop down value attribute to the database:angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports to print data in the database. I want to pass the value of the drop down as a parameter to the database. but my code gives an error saying  Input string was not in a correct format. Below is a sample of my code.

This is my html code.

```
 <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select kendo-drop-down-list
       name="PaymentCategory"
       class="k-fill"
       ng-init="Init()"
       ng-model="ReceiptCancelWF.PaymentCategory"
       k-placeholder="'Select Payment Category'"
       k-data-text-field="'text'"
       k-data-text-field="'Value'"
       k-data-value-field="'Key'"
       k-data-source="PaymentCategoryDropdown"
       ng-disabled="ReceiptCancelWF.AllPayCat"></select>
  </div>
```

This is my front end code.

```
 $scope.PaymentCategoryDropdown = [
         { "text": "Select", "value": 0 },
         { "text": "AR", "value": 1 },
         { "text": "CB", "value": 4 },

        ];

 $scope.PrintEntry = function (form) {
  var PaymentCategory = $scope.ReceiptCancelWF.PaymentCategory;
   PrintService.OpenPrint('POST', appConfig.REPORT_URL + 'CPOSReportViewer.aspx', { type: "ReceiptCancellationWF", PaymentCategory: PaymentCategory},'_blank'
 };
```

This is my back end code.

```
myReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CPOSReport/MIS/CancellationReports/ReceiptCancellationWorkFlow.rpt"));

             myReport.SetParameterValue("@EntryType", Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PaymentCategory"]));
```

I want to pass the value attribute as a integer to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I change my html code and frond end code as below.

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
<select kendo-drop-down-list
   name="PaymentCategory"
   class="k-fill"
   ng-init="Init()"
   ng-model="ReceiptCancelWF.PaymentCategory"
   k-placeholder="'Select Payment Category'"
   k-data-text-field="'text'"
   k-data-value-field="'value'"
   k-data-source="PaymentCategoryDropdown"
   ng-disabled="ReceiptCancelWF.AllPayCat"></select>
```

```
$scope.PaymentCategoryDropdown = [
     { "text": "Select", "value": "0" },
     { "text": "AR", "value": "1" },
     { "text": "CB", "value": "4" },

    ];
```